# Making a main method to test linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, program-entry-point

I need help to make a main method to test this program I've made for an assignment
Write a method to merge two linked lists of integers that are sorted into descending order. The result should be a third linked list that is the sorted combination of the original lists. Do not destroy the original lists.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Exercise6
{
    public static LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> a,LinkedList<Integer> b)
    {
    //Initialize variables
    LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> aI = a.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> bI = b.iterator();
    int aTemp = 0;
    int bTemp = 0;

    //Get the  first values from both lists using the next method
    aTemp = aI.next();
    bTemp = bI.next();

    while(aI.hasNext() && bI.hasNext())
    {
        //Comparing the two elements
        if(aTemp > bTemp)
        {
            result.add(bTemp);
            bTemp = bI.next();
        }
    }

    if(!aI.hasNext())
    {
        result.add(aTemp);
    }

    while(aI.hasNext())
    {
        result.add(aTemp);
        aTemp = aI.next();
    }

    while(bI.hasNext())
    {
        result.add(bTemp);
        bTemp = bI.next();
    }

    if(!aI.hasNext())
    {
        result.add(aTemp);
    }
    else
    {
        result.add(bTemp);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: What help do you need? Buying some energy drinks for you?

Comment: @MikeCAT I think he wants a driver for his program? Im confused as well .

Comment: No, I understand how linked-lists work to the extend of writing the program, that being if my code is correct, I'm just not sure how to test it as in to  declare two and then call the method on both of them? But I won't mind some energy drinks...

Comment: Yes, a driver method or just a code for testing since I could always turn it into a JUnit test instead of a driver class

Comment: Create two lists of predefined values in descending order (`5,3,1` and `6,4,2`) merge them and check that you get `6,5,4,3,2,1`. Finally, I would **highly** recommend you program to the `List` interface (and I see no reason you couldn't make your merge *generic*).

Comment: I'll definitely try that out right now! Thanks, what do you mean by "generic" we haven't learnt about that

Comment: What is `Integer` in `LinkedList<Integer>`?

Comment: The data type of the LinkedList

Comment: @DarkV1 **No**. That is a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you are asking for:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list1.add(9);
list1.add(7);
list1.add(3);
LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list1.add(8);
list1.add(5);
list1.add(1);
Exercise6 test = new Exercise6();
test.merge(list1,list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing an `else` for your `if` in `while(aI.hasNext() && bI.hasNext())`. Next, I would *strongly* recommend you program to the `List` interface (instead of the concrete `LinkedList` type). Also, I would make the `merge` method *generic* on some comparable type `T`. Something like,

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    // Initialize variables
    List<T> result = new LinkedList<>();
    Iterator<T> aI = a.iterator();
    Iterator<T> bI = b.iterator();
    // Get the first values from both lists using the next method
    T aTemp = aI.hasNext() ? aI.next() : null;
    T bTemp = bI.hasNext() ? bI.next() : null;
    while (aI.hasNext() && bI.hasNext()) {
        // Comparing the two elements
        if (aTemp.compareTo(bTemp) < 0) {
            result.add(bTemp); // <-- add the right-hand side
            bTemp = bI.next();
        } else {
            result.add(aTemp); // <-- add the left-hand side
            aTemp = aI.next();
        }
    }
    // Add the final two values from the loop.
    if (aTemp.compareTo(bTemp) < 0) {
        result.add(bTemp);
        result.add(aTemp);
    } else {
        result.add(aTemp);
        result.add(bTemp);
    }
    while (aI.hasNext()) { // Add any remaining values from a
        result.add(aI.next());
    }
    while (bI.hasNext()) { // Add any remaining values from b
        result.add(bI.next());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can test `merge` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(merge(Arrays.asList(6, 4, 2), Arrays.asList(5, 3, 1)));
    System.out.println(merge(Arrays.asList("bat", "ant"), 
            Arrays.asList("dog", "cat")));
}
```

I get

```
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[dog, cat, bat, ant]
```

Answer (score 0):

So do you write your code without ever testing it? I would suggest you get familiar with writing driver classes since as your code gets bigger you will need to test it along the way.

1. Create another class in the same package of your Exercise class: you can call it ExerciseDriver. Import classes as needed.
2. Declare Initialize and populate two linked lists. Declare a third linked lost to store the result.
3. Call the *static method* of your Exercise6 class
4. Print the result to verify

You could do something like:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public Class ExcerciseDriver{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> resultList;

        list1.add(77);
        list1.add(7);
        list1.add(6);

        list2.add(100);
        list2.add(43);
        list2.add(8);

        resultList = Excercise6.merge(list1, list2);

        System.out.println(resultList);
   }
}
```

Now all you have to do is running the *main* method and verify the correctness of your algorithm